# Dealing with empty data while inserting text data in MySql via python script

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am reading and storing data in MySQL and some columns data consists of empty values. e.g

```
#"ssd","mode","tolfil","slm.dat","Avg.dat","GP","13","gpro"
#"TIMESTAMP","Reco.no","teminF","ver.ang","hori.ang","vel","sd","vel.data"

"2009-02-25 14:28:36.76", ,8.277527,0.68,0.15,0.42,762.0303,4.6801
"2009-02-25 14:28:36.8", ,8.24408,0.7,0.03,0.3,761.878,4.682412
"2009-02-25 14:29:36.88",2,8.277527,0.55,0.09,0.31,762.0018,4.680709
 "2009-02-25 14:30:36.92",3,8.277527,0.47,0.2,0.31,761.8914,4.684526
```

so I got the following error.

```
[1456411716, ' ', '8.277527', '0.68', '0.15', '0.42', '762.0303', '4.6801']

mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265 (01000): 
Data truncated for column 'Reco.no' at row 1
```

My code is here:

```
 with open(filepath) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    max_lines = len(lines)
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        if k >= (int(skip_header_line) + int(index_line_number)):
            data_tmp = line.strip().split(',')

            strDate = data_tmp[0].replace("\"", "")
        strDate = strDate.split('.')[0]   
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
        ts = calendar.timegm(timestamp.timetuple())           
      #  _ts = ts * 1000000 

            data_buffer = [ts] + data_tmp[1:]                                                                    
            print data_buffer
            cursor.execute(add_data, data_buffer)
            cnx.commit()

            with open(marker_file, "w") as f:
                f.write(" ".join([ str(item[0]), str(data_tmp[0]), str(max_lines),
                       str(k-int(skip_header_line)+1) ]))
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

if I do like this

```
            data_buffer = [ts] + data_tmp[1:]           
            for val in data_buffer:
                if val == '':
                    val = None
                    data_buffer.append(val)  
                else:
                    data_buffer.append(float(val))



            print data_buffer
```

then I got different error

```
 ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Actually I know how to deal with null data but in the above mention code I am not sure where to tell it that when it come across the empty space, it should put read and insert as NULL in MySql database.

Any help will be really appreciated .

Comment: is this something that can't be done wtih LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: @e4c5 I didn't try with LOAD DATA INFILE . I will give it a try. is LOAD DATA INFILE deals with empty data automatically?    I think I can use it within python script. also my file is 11 GB. which consists of alot of lines.

Comment: @e4c5 but at the moment can you give me a hint or clue to deal with missing columns data through my code. thanx in advance for help.

Comment: All those lots of lines you speak of maybe replaceable by a single LOAD DATA INFILE command typed into the mysql console. No it doesn't handle missing columns by itself, ou have to tell it how to handle them and/or set defaults, nullable columns in your table.

Comment: @e4c5 well data is missing randomly across different columns. sometimes columns have data and sometimes not. mean every column at some stage has missing data except timestamp which is the first column.

Comment: @e4c5 thanx for the tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer I found which works perfectly well is ..

```
  data_buffer = [ts] + data_tmp[1:]
  data_buffer = [v if v is not "" and v is not " " else None for v in data_buffer]
  print data_buffer
```